# how to position smartGWT dialog

Tags: smartgwt

I am trying for hours now  to move my dialog in smartGWT, but with no luck.

This is my code:

```
            Dialog dlg = new Dialog();

            ListGridRecord[] h = scoringGrid.getRecords();
            HLayout chart = new HLayout();
            vlayout.addMember(chart);

            dlg.addMember(highChart(h));
            dlg.moveBy(500, 900);
            dlg.setHeight("400px");
            dlg.setWidth("700px");
            dlg.show();
```

I also tried: `setLeft, setTop, setRect,` without any effect.
My dialog always displays at the same location.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure your are publishing your changes correctly?

Comment: Are you working on updated code? Sometimes a rerun is needed. Also as @Alain said, maybe it isn't being redrawn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dialog is a subClass of Window. So you can invoke the method setRect which is inherited.

*From the Javadoc:*

```
public void setRect(int left, int top, int width,  int height)
```

//        Set all four coordinates, relative to the enclosing context, at once.

If you don't see the change perhaps you would have to redraw in some cases I found it necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I finally tried calling moveTo() **after** show(), and it worked.

```
dlg.show();
dlg.moveTo(400, 500);
```

moveBy() works this way as well.

I'm not sure WHY this works--I'm guessing show() automatically centers the Dialog and overrides previous placement.  However, I don't get the same behavior working with a Window, and I don't see anything in Dialog overriding the show() behavior. But, it worked for me....